# wordpress links after transfering from Local Wamp to server not working

Tags: database, wordpress, hyperlink, localhost

I have a compelete Wordpress site in my localhost(Wamp Server) ,I have Uploaded All files and directories in my server

I have exported my Database by WP Migrate DB plugin , and imported it into my server database , but when I click on a link this error will be shown :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /2379-2/ was not found on this server.

While I think the addres is ok :
In wamp : http://localhost/wordPress/2379-2/    --------> Works

In online server : http://fcop.ir/2379-2/ ------>abave error

Comment: Check your permalink settings

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go into the wp_options table of the database and change the `siteurl` and `home` to your live site url: 'http://fcop.ir'. You can find `siteurl` and `home` by searching the option_name column.